# Get Logged in User Name from Azure without Graph API

Tags: azure

I have logged a user into their Azure AD account.  I am able to discover their endpoints.  How do I find the user's name (and / or email address) without having to give permission to the Azure Graph API?

The user currently has access to "Windows Azure Active Directory:Sign in and read user Profile".  But I would like to simply discover the logged in user name using REST (I'm using JavaScript).  All the Googling for this results in links to the Graph API.  Isn't there a simple Azure AD REST API?  I don't want to use ADAL or some other library just to get a user name if possible!

The endpoints that the user has are MyFiles v1.0 and MyFiles v2.0.  That's all.

Comment: You want to retrieve the user name/email from a web api, mvc website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:  When the user authenticates, an id_token is returned along with the access_token.  This token is a JWT which you can decode.  It includes the user display name (name) and email address (unique_name).

Comment: How exactly do you get this `id_token`?